# How to access one functional component's state from another functional component in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I want to access **ModalView's** state from MarkerView component. Actually i want to see ModalView when i click **Get info.** button which is in **MarkerView**. I want to set { *setVisiblity(true)*} from **MarkerView** component. How can i do it?

**ModalView.js**

```
const ModalView = () => {
    
    const [visiblity, setVisiblity] = useState(false);

    return (
        <Modal transparent={false} visible={visiblity} >

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { setVisiblity(false)}}>
                <Text> Submit </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

        </Modal>
    )
}
```

**MarkerView.js**

```
const MarkerView = () => {

    return (
        // i want to set visiblity true from here
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { setVisiblity(true) }}> 
                    <Text>Get info.</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}
```

**App.js**

```
import ModalVIew from './components/ModalView';
import Marker from './components/MarkerView';

const App = () => {

  return (

      <View>
        <Marker/>
        <ModalVIew/>

      </View>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use state management like [contextAPI](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or [redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started), or you can put your state on your higher order component but this will result in some prop drilling.

App.js

```
 const App = () => {
    const [visiblity, setVisiblity] = useState(false);
    
      return (
    
          <View>
            <Marker visiblity={visiblity} onChangeVisiblity={(val) => setVisiblity(val)}/>
            <ModalVIew visiblity={visiblity} onChangeVisiblity={(val) => setVisiblity(val)}/>
    
          </View>
      )
    }
```

MarkerView.js

```
const MarkerView = ({visiblity, onChangeVisiblity: changeVisiblity}) => {

    return (
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => changeVisiblity(true)}> 
                    <Text>Get info.</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}
```

ModalView.js

```
const ModalView = ({visiblity, onChangeVisiblity:changeVisiblity}) => {
    
    const [visiblity, setVisiblity] = useState(false);

    return (
        <Modal transparent={false} visible={visiblity} >

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => changeVisiblity(false)}>
                <Text> Submit </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

        </Modal>
    )
}
```

Comment: @JimKhan anytime :)